# Two UILabels under each other, hide the top one

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

As described in the title, I have an app with two UILabels under each other. If I want to hide to top one programmatically, it's possible with myLabel.hidden = true.

If I'm doing this in Android (with myLabel.setVisibility(View.Gone);), the label under this label will move up.

But if I'm doing it for iOS, the label is hidden, but there still an empty space instead of the label.

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: what are we suppose to see in that screenshot ? Also are you sure you got two labels ?

Comment: @Vince Well, I have three labels of course. If I hide the second one, the third one should be positioned under the first one. 
In the screenshot, you can see the empty space if you hide a label.

Comment: the label won't move up itself, change its `frame` to do that.

Comment: He means: http://pastie.org/pastes/3250072/text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When hiding the second one, get its frame, hide it and change the frame property of the third :

```
CGRect secondFrame = secondLabel.frame;
secondLabel.hidden = YES;
thirdLabel.frame = secondFrame;
```

Comment: That does work, thanks for that. 
But the point is: I have 8 labels underneath each other. Each label content can be empty, and if it's empty it shouldn't be shown. 
That means that I have to change quite a lot of frames.. =/

Comment: sorry, didn't know the details. Of course this situation is bit more complicated, you will have to imagine such mechanism. The general idea here is that the labels won't move up themselves, even if they are empty or hidden

Comment: @harmjanr for iOS simply rebuild the view containing all labels if one of them changes

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{label1.alpha = 0;
                              label2.frame = label1.frame}
                 completion:NULL];
```